# Android Studio 2.0 Application crash on unmodified Application class

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a really weird Android Studio 2.0 problem. If I edit my application class file, even just adding a couple of spaces, my app launches just fine. If I don't edit it, it crashes with:

```
11-23 18:17:44.694 30811-30811/******.******.com.****** E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ******.******.com.******, PID: 30811
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application ******.******.com.******.application.******: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "******.******.com.******.application.******" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/******.******.com.******-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/******.******.com.******-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4382)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "******.******.com.******.application.******" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/******.******.com.******-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/******.******.com.******-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:998)
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4382) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my application class:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        context = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

and here's my module `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.20.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias *********
            keyPassword **********
            storePassword ***********
            storeFile **********
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ***************
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':boilerplate')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.5l'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
}
```

Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="******" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LaunchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Activities, etc. -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Anyone had this issue before? It's is if it's not compiling the application file unless it's changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was just a bug. Closing now.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue by changing the classpath of android build tool
(e.g: classpath '`com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0`')

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you added the class as application name in your manifest application tag like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:name=".App" //Your Application Class
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sample" >
....
</application>
</manifest>
```